# How to see available commands that end with a certain string?

Tags: command-line, bash, auto-completion

If you start typing and pressing tab the console tries to expand and show all commands, functions and executable scripts that begin with what you have started to write.

Is there a way to see which commands the typed string anywhere in their names? Not necessarily with tab completion, but with some small function or script.

I may remember a command that has `font` in its name, but not in the beginning. How to make it show `mkfontdir` and all the others?

Or I may have a script with font somewhere in the name but not in the beginning (like my-fonts.py).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I normally do a find command like this

```
find / -executable -name '*'font 2>/dev/null
```

Which would result on my computer the following

```
/usr/bin/showconsolefont
/usr/bin/gnome-thumbnail-font
/usr/bin/splitfont
/usr/bin/showfont
/usr/bin/grub-mkfont
/usr/share/doc/ttf-freefont
/usr/share/doc/fonts-horai-umefont
/usr/share/doc/ttf-umefont
/usr/share/groff/1.21/font
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/freefont
/usr/share/fonts/truetype/horai-umefont
/bin/setfont
```

Although this command will be a little tighter in its results

```
find / -type f -perm +111 -name '*'font 2>/dev/null
```

Returns

```
/usr/bin/showconsolefont
/usr/bin/gnome-thumbnail-font
/usr/bin/splitfont
/usr/bin/showfont
/usr/bin/grub-mkfont
/bin/setfont
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the `find` command Doogfar suggested takes ages to run, you can add a cronjob to run it once in a while sending it to a file:

```
find / -type f -perm +111 >~/.perm111 2>/dev/null &
```

and then a quick grep when you need it.

```
grep font ~/.perm111
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an Ubuntu box, but this command is available on OS X and OpenSUSE:

```
compgen -ac | grep someStringInCommandName
```

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948008/linux-command-to-list-all-available-commands-and-aliases